# export selected checkstyle to document

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I'm configuring checkstyle in Eclipse. During configuration of the different rules, the editor shows the rationale of a certain rule such as the description of cyclomatic complexity:

> Checks cyclomatic complexity against a specified limit. The complexity is measured by the number of if, while, do, for, ?:, catch, switch, case statements, and operators && and || (plus one) in the body of a constructor, method, static initializer, or instance initializer. It is a measure of the minimum number of possible paths through the source and therefore the number of required tests. Generally 1-4 is considered good, 5-7 ok, 8-10 consider re-factoring, and 11+ re-factor now!

This is valuable information and I would like to export this kind of information from the selected rules in checkstyle to a document that would make up most part of our coding guideliness. Is there a way to export the description of the enabled checkstyle rules to a simple text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Coding guidelines from CheckStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14462987/1005481).

Comment: Hi Thomas, guess its the same question, although not the satisfying answer.